# UISegue is not presenting new view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have come across something so weird that my only option is to ask for help on here.  I have three view controllers in a workflow.  I am able to segue from View Controller A to B with no problem.  All of a sudden I am unable to segue from View Controller B to C.  I have verified that all of the following methods have fired:

- viewWillDissapear (View Controller B)
- viewDidDissapear (View Controller B)
- viewWillAppear (View Controller C)
- viewDidAppear (ViewController C)

I tried deleting the segue and remaking it in IB.  I also cleaned the project and re-compiled it.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So as is often the case with inexplicable problems, the answer is very dull and uneventful.  I deleted the app from my test iPhone and reinstalled it and it worked great.  However, I did have labels on the three view controllers that had identical names . . . so I am renaming those just to be safe.